# Azure app registration with Microsoft Graph permissions anomaly

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

I registered an app on azure which requires a graph API 'Application' permission of Calendars.ReadWrite, however when a user goes through the auth flow to grant the app access it asks for the following permissions:

This app would like to:

- Read and write calendars in all mailboxes
- Sign in and read user profile

I am not sure where this second permission has come from? It looks like we are asking for more rights than I was intending. Is the second permission required in order for the first to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Is the second permission required in order for the first to work?***

> Yes its required if your user trying to access that using [`auth code flow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) because it requires `dedicated permission` but you have
>   assigned `Application permission`.

***`Solution Could Be`***

> If you try other authentication flow like [`client_credentials`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) for example
>   you wouldn't be prompted for second permission in your case.

So now its your turns whether you would use `auth code grant`(Which need `Dedicated permission`) or `client_credentials`(which uses `Application permission`)

Hope above information would help you.